# Why simple AJAX functionality is not working in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to change the message on the button click with ajax in laravel but for some reason, it is not working. I searched it online. Most of the insertion of jquery or ajax links is a problem. I think I've entered that correctly, I don't know what else can be an issue.

There is also no issue in the console of the browser.

Scripts Links in my main `layouts.app` class

```dart
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    {{-- <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/custom.js') }}"></script> --}}

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>
    <!-- JQUERY -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/assets/js/tabledit.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.3.2.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-Ap4KLoCf1rXb52q+i3p0k2vjBsmownyBTE1EqlRiMwA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap js -->
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-VHvPCCyXqtD5DqJeNxl2dtTyhF78xXNXdkwX1CZeRusQfRKp+tA7hAShOK/B/fQ2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
```

Code inside `.blade.php`

```
    <div id='msg'>This message will be replaced using Ajax. Click the button to replace the message.</div>
    <button id='btn' type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-rounded btn-sm my-0">
        Replace Message
    </button>
```

`ajax` script inside the same blade.

```dart
<script>
$(document).ready(
   $("#btn").on("click", 
        function() {
        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'/getmsg',
          data:'csrf-token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
          success:function(data) {
            dd(":1");
             $("#msg").html(data.msg);
            }
        });
      }); 
    )
</script>
```

`web.php` linking

```dart
Route::post('/getmsg', [CustomerController::class, 'index']);
```

`index` function inside the `CustomerController`

```dart
    public function index()
    {
        $msg = "This is a simple message.";
        return response()->json(array('msg' => $msg), 200);
    }
```

Comment: are you checking `console` and `network` tab that no errors and properly ajax calling?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra No there is non. I have checked it. https://i2.paste.pics/1b9a861cc02343470191f89279e09b69.png?trs=4dc922e8b1dcf0d24ba45a7d216a34f726b654201d96c7c9551708a7972418c8

Comment: please remove dd(":1"); and add console.log(data) then check

Comment: @WaseemAhmad I have removed `dd(":1"); ` and added a `console.log` like this but still no change on console or UI
`success:function(data) {
            console.log(data); 
             $("#msg").html(data.msg);
            }`

Comment: change  data:'csrf-token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>', to   data: {
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
        }

Comment: @JohnLobo still nothing changed :(

Comment: Probably unrelated: loading `jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js`, `jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js` and `jquery-3.6.0.min.js` seems like a little too much

Comment: "_No there is non. I have checked it._" That screenshot shows "_2 issues_" though, are they not related?

Comment: @brombeer I'm actually new. I only saw `migrate is installed` in the console. Was it an issue? I'm not sure where are 2 issues. Can you please help?

Comment: What browser are you using? Have you tried clicking on the "2 issues"?

Comment: @brombeer now only one left. When I click on that `issue` at top right corner, nothing happens

Comment: @brombeer here is the issue in the console https://i.ibb.co/LrJ2SY2/Screenshot-2022-05-21-112927.jpg

Answer (score 0):

1. First comment :
    `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>`
2. Use only one version of jquery.min.js

Also remember that always include jquery.min.js file on top of all other js files.

Here is full code from demo I have performed :

Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CustomController extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        $msg = "This is a simple message.";
        return response()->json(array('msg' => $msg), 200);
    }

    public function myview() {
        return view('test');
    }

}
```

Routes :

```
Route::post('/getmsg', [CustomController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/getview', [CustomController::class, 'myview']);
```

View (test.blade.php) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <title>Laravel</title>
    </head>
    <body class="antialiased">
        <div id='msg'>This message will be replaced using Ajax. Click the button to replace the message.</div>
        <button id='btn' type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-rounded btn-sm my-0">
            Replace Message
        </button>
    </body>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('click', '#btn', function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/getmsg',
                    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#msg").html(data.msg);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: There are currently 3. Which should I keep? 
(1) `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js` 
(2) `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js` 
(3) `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js` I added as people suggested in different solutions

Comment: I did everything as you suggested. I followed point 1 then 2 and only left `script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` and then I pasted your code.  But now I get a small error in console `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/getmsg 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Use Jquery : 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js

Also use only one bootstrap js file :
//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: I did same, I only have these scripts https://ctxt.io/2/AADgzLcXFw. But still same error in `console`

Comment: Can you try this order https://ctxt.io/2/AADgOkT7EA and also debug your route that control is reaching there or not.

Comment: I've copied the same code as you showed but it is not working for me, why?

Comment: I'm getting small issue in my `console` now after copying almost everything from your code `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/getmsg 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: This is the console erro. https://ibb.co/q0LD2Cb when I clicked on it  https://ibb.co/DbMmWfY

Comment: @FaizanKamal Take a look at your project's `laravel.log` file(s) to see more details.

Comment: @brombeer nothing much in the last few lines of `laravel.log`, probably unrelated

Comment: Last line `[2022-05-21 05:54:53] local.ERROR: Cannot redeclare isCustomerRecordValid() (previously declared in D:\Exafos\LOGX\logxProject\app\helpers.php:14) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError(code: 0): Cannot redeclare isCustomerRecordValid() (previously declared in D:\\Exafos\\LOGX\\logxProject\\app\\helpers.php:14) at D:\\Exafos\\LOGX\\logxProject\\app\\helpers.php:14)
[stacktrace]
#0 {main}
"} `